# Overflow-X not showing scrollbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a container that I'm using to hold a table, and I'm trying to apply the overflow-x property, but there's something wrong with it. I've got a working codepen that I'll post in a moment, but the problem is that it doesn't go responsive. When the viewport closes in on it, it just "sticks" (I can't really explain it better than that, the Codepen shows it though). Here is the code:

```
<section class='main-container'>
    <h6>Users</h6>

    <table>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class='name'>Name</th>
                <th class='email'>Email</th>
                <th class='role'>Role</th>
                <th class='status'>Status</th>
                <th class='alerts'>Alerts/Actions</th>
                <th class='delete'></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Joe Bob</td>
      <td class='email'>bobjoe@me.com</td>
      <td class='role'>This is the role</td>
      <td class='status'>Approved</td>
      <td class='alerts'>There's an alert</td>
      <td class='delete'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Joe Bob</td>
      <td class='email'>bobjoe@me.com</td>
      <td class='role'>This is the role</td>
      <td class='status'>Approved</td>
      <td class='alerts'>There's an alert</td>
      <td class='delete'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Joe Bob</td>
      <td class='email'>bobjoe@me.com</td>
      <td class='role'>This is the role</td>
      <td class='status'>Approved</td>
      <td class='alerts'>There's an alert</td>
      <td class='delete'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Joe Bob</td>
      <td class='email'>bobjoe@me.com</td>
      <td class='role'>This is the role</td>
      <td class='status'>Approved</td>
      <td class='alerts'>There's an alert</td>
      <td class='delete'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Joe Bob</td>
      <td class='email'>bobjoe@me.com</td>
      <td class='role'>This is the role</td>
      <td class='status'>Approved</td>
      <td class='alerts'>There's an alert</td>
      <td class='delete'></td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

</section>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    border: none;
    color: #425563;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.main-container {

    --away-left: 20px;
  --border-radius: 2px;
  --shine-brand-blue: #425563;
  --shine-gray-two: #eceeef;
  --shine-gray-one: #f1f2f3;

  display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
  max-width: 600px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow-x: scroll;

    h6 {
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 50px;
        font-family: var(--main-font);
        color: var(--shine-brand-blue);
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--shine-gray-two);
        padding-left: var(--away-left);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    table {
        margin: 25px 0;
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-collapse: collapse;

        th, td {
            text-align: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e3e5;
            &.name {min-width: 149px;}
            &.email {min-width: 230px;}
            &.role {min-width: 148px;}
            &.status {min-width: 82px;}
            &.alerts {min-width: 195px;}
            &.delete {min-width: 15px;}
        }

        th {
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #7d8d9a;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        td {  
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: 50px;
            color: var(--shine-brand-blue);

            select {
                height: 40px;
                width: 90%;
                min-width: 140px;
                border-radius: var(--border-radius);
                background-color: var(--shine-gray-one);
                cursor: pointer;
            }

        }

        tbody tr { 
            transition: all .3s;

            &:hover { background-color: #f5f6f7; }

        }

    }
}

main.next-to-aside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

**How can I get the table to act responsive instead of just "sticking" like how it does in this Codepen?:** https://codepen.io/adammcgurk/pen/aXyZxm

Comment: https://codepen.io/josh-cranwell/pen/QYMKab i wrapped the table in a div called `.table-fluid` a bit like how bootstrap do it. Not sure if this helps. Moved your overflow css to the div.

Comment: Are you seeing the same issue across browsers AND devices? Or is it limited to one environment?

Comment: Can you precise in which browser you have this issue ? it seems working when i tested it.

Comment: @AdamMcGurk I tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Opera (on windows in a resized window) with no issue. Is it it a device issue? Recommend clearing the cache of your browser for a start..

Comment: your main-container class scroll bar is not working right?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually had to wrap the table in a `div`. Using only the `section` wouldn't work, because it contained more children than just the `table`. So the boilerplate code looked like this:

```
<style>
    .responsive-table {
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
</style>

<section class='main-container'>
    <!-- other content -->
    <div class='responsive-table'>
        <table>
             <!-- table content -->
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```